# Magento 2: How to get address from customer's object?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to get country, state and city of a customer. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If you need all addresses data then used:

```
$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
if(count($addresses)) {
  foreach($addresses as $addresse) {
      echo $addresse->getCountryId();
      echo '<br>';
      echo $addresse->getCity();
      echo '<br>';
      echo $addresse->getRegionId();
      echo '<br>';
      echo $addresse->getRegion();

  }
}
```

If you need the default billing address data then used:

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress(); 
echo $billingAddress->getCountryId();
echo '<br>';
echo $billingAddress->getCity();
echo '<br>';
echo $billingAddress->getRegionId();
echo '<br>';
echo $billingAddress->getRegion();
```

If you need the default shipping address data then used:

```
$shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress(); 
echo $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getCity();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getRegionId();
echo '<br>';
echo $shippingAddress->getRegion();
```

Here `$customer` is you customer object

Comment: how to get region?

Comment: $addresse->getState(); not working

Comment: try $addresse->getRegionId();

Comment: Update ans pls check

Comment: are you need state full name or state code/id?

Comment: how to get state full name with this

Answer (score 3):

**You can get address object using below way,**
Just check and let me know if you have any issue,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository        
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function getAddressofCustomer(){
    $customerId = 1;
    $addresses = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId)->getAddresses();

    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $customerAddress = $address->__toArray();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($customerAddress);
        echo 'Region '.$customerAddress['region']['region'];
        echo 'Country Id '.$customerAddress['country_id'];
        echo 'City '.$customerAddress['city'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before get customer country, state and city. You need to load customer then you will get these data from address for a customer.

Try this :

```
$customerID = 10;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerID);

$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
foreach($addresses as $address)
{
  echo $address->getCountryId();
  echo $address->getRegionId();
  echo $address->getCity();
  break;
}
```

I checked this and it's works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The customer can have multiple addresses(Billing & Shipping) in account dashboard. From the question, It is not clear that which data you want (I mean by default billing/shipping address or last one).

Suppose If you have `$customer` object then you can get `country`, `state`, `city` like this from default billing adress,

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress(); 

if($billingAddress){
      $city=$billingAddress->getCity();
      $state=$billingAddress->getRegion();
      $countryId=$billingAddress->getCountry()
}
```

If you want this data from default shipping address then you can get it like this,

```
   $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress(); 

    if($shippingAddress){
          $city=$shippingAddress->getCity();
          $state=$shippingAddress->getRegion();
          $countryId=$shippingAddress->getCountry()
    }
```